# Signalr persistent connection with query params.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

I have a persistent connection which I would like to start with some seed info using query params.  Here is the override in the connection.

```
    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        //GET QUERY PARAMS HERE

        return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
    }
```

Now I have my route setup in global.asax file which looks like this.

> RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection("myconnection",
>   "/myconnection");

And the client code looks like this

```
var connection = $.connection('/myconnection');

connection.start()
          .done(() =>
          {
          });
```

Can someone tell me how I can pass query string params to this connecton so I can read them in the override as I seem to be hitting a brick wall on this.

Cheers hope someone can help,

Dave

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**HUBS**

```
   var connection = $.connection('/myconnection');
    $.connection.hub.qs = "name=John"; //pass your query string
```

and to get it on the server

```
var myQS = Context.QueryString["name"];
```

To access your query string in javascript you could use something like

```
function getQueryStringValueByKey(key) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var values = url.split(/[\?&]+/);
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var value = values[i].split("=");
            if (value[0] == key) {
                return value[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Call it:

```
var name = getQueryStringValueByKey("name");
```

**PERSISTENT CONNECTION**

```
//pass your query string
var connection = $.connection('/myconnection', "name=John", true);

protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        //get the name here
        var name = request.QueryString["name"];

        return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
    }
```

Here is the source code where you can find out more: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.core.js#L106

Comment: I'm not using hubs I am using a persistent connection type.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the answer. Please mark if this is what you wanted.

Comment: hey that works a treat.  Had been trying to munge it into the route descripter or the actually path I was hitting.  Hadn't realized there was this overload.  Awesome!

Comment: @user231300 glad it helped. Updated my answer so it's clearly to see how to use querystring with hubs and persistent connection.

Comment: Also note that you can pass the qs property into the $.connection constructor.  AKA $.connection(url, qs)

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen Thanks for pointing it out.It's really the same as $.connection('/myconnection', "name=John", true); but with omitted logging at the end as it's default value is false.

Comment: how would this work for multiple parameter? or would you send the string and parse at the server side?