# SignalR ASP.NET Core 3.1- How to get call-specific data from outside of hub?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a Web API where a controller has an interface injected into it, and that interface, call it `ISystem`, can be an instance of multiple different classes, lets say `System1` and `System2`. Depending on a value passed in the HTTP header of the API call, I create a concrete instance of either `System1` or `System2` for the scope of a given request. I use the `AddScoped()` constructor that takes a factory method and in that factory method I get an instance of `HttpContextAccessor` to get to current `HttpContext` and check the headers, and build the appropriate concrete class.

I now have added a SignalR hub to this API and the hub also requires an instance of this same interface, currently injected into the hub constructor.

My issue is I have no idea how I can get some user-specific piece of data for the hub method caller caller to use in the `AddScoped()` factory, and so I have no way to know which concrete `ISystem` class to create when a call comes in to my hub.  The hub does not require authentication.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more and show your code for the Hub method, what user-specific data are you looking for? User Auth data or data stored in the database etc? You should edit your question and explain more :)

Comment: On the Web API an HTTP Header is included to specify "System ID" which is used to determine which "System" concrete class to use in the AddScope() factory.  I need to accomplish the same thing via SignalR, i.e. I need to be able to determine the "System ID" of the client making the call to the hub in the AddScope() factory.

Comment: You want to pass a parameter to SignalR hub? as you are passing the HTTP Header to API?

Comment: Yes and I want to be able to access that parameter from the AddScoped() factory method so I can use it to determine which concrete class to instantiate for the scope of the current call.

Comment: What client are you using? In javascript, you can send any parameter to a hub as QueryString like `$.connection.hub.qs = "your parameter"` In any case please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183176/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-hub-in-signalr AND This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585100/signalr-persistent-connection-with-query-params